# How get the text from the <p> tag using XPath Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, getattribute

I need to catch with XPath one line from a text inside a `<p>`. I need to store the text `Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii` into a variable in python but i get the next error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: Expected an element or WindowProxy, got: [object Text] {}`

Here is the code im trying:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html')

foo = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p[5]/text()')
print(foo)
```

```html
<h1>7.1  The Text Content-Type</h1>
<p>
The text Content-Type is intended for sending material which
is  principally textual in form.  It is the default Content-
Type.  A "charset" parameter may be  used  to  indicate  the
character set of the body text.  The primary subtype of text
is "plain".  This indicates plain (unformatted)  text.   The
default  Content-Type  for  Internet  mail  is  "text/plain;
charset=us-ascii".
<p>
Beyond plain text, there are many formats  for  representing
what might be known as "extended text" -- text with embedded
formatting and  presentation  information.   An  interesting
characteristic of many such representations is that they are
to some extent  readable  even  without  the  software  that
interprets  them.   It is useful, then, to distinguish them,
at the highest level, from such unreadable data  as  images,
audio,  or  text  represented in an unreadable form.  In the
absence  of  appropriate  interpretation  software,  it   is
reasonable to show subtypes of text to the user, while it is
not reasonable to do so with most nontextual data.
<p>
Such formatted textual  data  should  be  represented  using
subtypes  of text.  Plausible subtypes of text are typically
given by the common name of the representation format, e.g.,
"text/richtext".
<p>
<h3>7.1.1     The charset parameter</h3>
<p>
A critical parameter that may be specified in  the  Content-
Type  field  for  text  data  is the character set.  This is
specified with a "charset" parameter, as in:
<p>
     Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
<p>
Unlike some  other  parameter  values,  the  values  of  the
charset  parameter  are  NOT  case  sensitive.   The default
character set, which must be assumed in  the  absence  of  a
charset parameter, is US-ASCII.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the text **Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(., 'The charset parameter')]//following-sibling::p[2]"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html")
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[contains(., 'The charset parameter')]//following-sibling::p[2]"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Content-type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works in this example, but im trying now to apply to this other example and im not able to catch the 'User' line.


`<br />
Hi User!,<br />
Your apply has been accepted!.<br />
<br />
Take your data:<br />
--------------------------<br />
� User: name<br />
� Pass: 12345678<br />
--------------------------<br />
Good Bye<br />
<br />`

Comment: Am getting TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 3):

The `text()` in the xpath is the issue here, see below:

```
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_1_Text.html')

foo = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/p[5]')
print(foo.text)
```